# When i created my location tracker app it works fine.But once i turned off my device where i installed it gives me the exception in android

Tags: android

When i created the app first time there were no problem what so ever.But once i turned off my device and restarts it again it couldn't find the actual location or last known location.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-29 10:35:18.847 23147-23147/com.example.preciset3.uberapp E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.preciset3.uberapp, PID: 23147
02-29 10:35:18.847 23147-23147/com.example.preciset3.uberapp E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: **Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference**
02-29 10:35:18.847 23147-23147/com.example.preciset3.uberapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.preciset3.uberapp.Rider.onMapReady(Rider.java:190)
02-29 10:35:18.847 23147-23147/com.example.preciset3.uberapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
02-29 10:35:18.847 23147-23147/com.example.preciset3.uberapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzo$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
02-29 10:35:18.847 23147-23147/com.example.preciset3.uberapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
02-29 10:35:18.847 23147-23147/com.example.preciset3.uberapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.be.a(SourceFile:82)
02-29 10:35:18.847 23147-23147/com.example.preciset3.uberapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.fb.run(Unknown Source)
02-29 10:35:18.847 23147-23147/com.example.preciset3.uberapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
02-29 10:35:18.847 23147-23147/com.example.preciset3.uberapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-29 10:35:18.847 23147-23147/com.example.preciset3.uberapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
02-29 10:35:18.847 23147-23147/com.example.preciset3.uberapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
02-29 10:35:18.847 23147-23147/com.example.preciset3.uberapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-29 10:35:18.847 23147-23147/com.example.preciset3.uberapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
02-29 10:35:18.847 23147-23147/com.example.preciset3.uberapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
02-29 10:40:18.858 23147-23147/com.example.preciset3.uberapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 23147 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You called getLatitude on a null pointer.  Let me guess-  you called getLastKnownLocation(), didn't you?  getLastKnownLocation will return null if it doesn't have a location yet, which is most of the time if no location has been requested yet.  You have to check for null and wait until a requestLocationUpdates or requestSingleLocation callback is made.

Comment: Gabe Sechan@ you are right...After sometimes i got the location updation..Can you suggest me some other ways where i can get the app to be in progress even if the location isn't changed.Like how to implement that requestSingleLocation callback in detail.Could you make the things clearer.

Comment: See LocationManager for requestSingleLocation.  It works just like requestLocationUpdates, but will only be called once.  The difference from it and getLastKnownLocation is the requestXXX calls will turn on the location hardware in the phone.  getLastKnownLocation only works if it already happens to be on, or was in the recent past.